# Attributes are removed in HTML code

Tags: wysihtml5

I use wysihtml5.
When you insert an image

```
<img alt src="src" media_img_id="123" data-title="title" data-author="author" />
```

The result is

```
<img alt src="src" />
```

Rules for img

```
"img": {
    "remove": 0,
        "check_attributes": {
            "width": "numbers",
            "alt": "alt",
            "src": "url", // if you compiled master manually then change this from 'url' to 'src'
            "height": "numbers",
    "media_img_id": "numbers"
        },
        "add_class": {
            "align": "align_img"
        }
    },
```

How to make the attributes generally not removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same task today to extend abilities of this editor. 
You should add your attributes in special object:
I'm using additionaly bootstrap3-wysihtml5 - https://github.com/schnawel007/bootstrap3-wysihtml5 . The object that should be added with new attributes for element:

```
var defaultOptions = $.fn.wysihtml5.defaultOptions = { 
  /../

  "img": {
    "check_attributes": 
          {
      "width": "numbers",
      "alt": "alt",
      "data-encid": "alt", <<-here is my custom attribute
      "src": "url",
      "height": "numbers"
      }
    },

 /../
}
```

and in wysihtml5.js you should add condition in which your src attribute is differs from classical source (that this plugin expected) "http://example.png".

line 4922:

```
if (checkAttributes) {
      for (attributeName in checkAttributes) {
        method = attributeCheckMethods[checkAttributes[attributeName]];
        if (!method) {
          continue;
        }
        newAttributeValue = method(_getAttribute(oldNode, attributeName));
        if (typeof(newAttributeValue) === "string") {
          attributes[attributeName] = newAttributeValue;
        }
      }
    }
```

replace with:

```
if (checkAttributes) {
      for (attributeName in checkAttributes) {
        method = attributeCheckMethods[checkAttributes[attributeName]];
        if (!method) {
          continue;
        }
        newAttributeValue = (attributeName == "src" && checkAttributes["data-encid"])
            ? oldNode.src
            : method(_getAttribute(oldNode, attributeName));
        if (typeof(newAttributeValue) === "string") {
          attributes[attributeName] = newAttributeValue;
        }
      }
    }
```

Here I just copy the src attribute value without checking through wysihtml5.js core.

Hope this helps!